# How to mount ssh in 10.6

Tags: macos, ssh, sshfs

I have a mac with 10.6 and I want to use CCC over ssh.
How do i do this
I think sshfs might help

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/downloads/list), then follow [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS) for sshfs.

I'm not sure, but a software specifically designed for use over SSH, such as `rsync`, might perform better.